# Google Maps problem with Geocoder

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocode

The point is to point out the markers from a JSON file, but if the current json, dont have any lat and lng it should calculate it, but it dont work

```
//For example when
item.county = 'Orust'
//and 
item.region = 'Bohuslän'
```

Why is that?

```
if(lat == null)
            {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': item.county+', '+item.region}, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if(result[0])
                    {
                        latlng = result[0].geometry.location
                    }
                }
                });
```

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

First check to see if things are working as expected inside the callback.  To do that, change this:

```
latlng = result[0].geometry.location;
```

To this:

```
console.log(result[0].geometry.location);
```

(You can also just add the `console.log` above the `latlng` assignment rather than changing it.  Actually, that's probably better.)

If the resulting message in your JavaScript console looks like a `latlng` object, then the problem is likely a scope problem--in other words, `latlng` outside of the callback is not the same as `latlng` inside the callback.

If the resulting message in your JavaScript console does not look like a `latlng` object, then the problem is inside the callback itself.  Check to see if you are getting any results at all by putting this where you put the last `console.log()` above:

```
console.log(result);
```

If these `console.log` commands never fire and nothing appears in your JavaScript console, then the status returned from the `geocoder.geocoder()` is not `OK` and you need to add some error handling in the callback to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Request to geocoder runs asynchronously. You cannot access to vriable which is assigned inside the callback from the outside code. Actually you could but it will be undefined.